.NET MAUI: How do I predict/calculate widths and heights relative to physical screen size?
Trying to port some old code and not sure how to translate a screen size measurement intended to be in defined in inches to the units MAUI is using. It seems like DisplayInfo's Width and Height properties and Density are not sufficient for me to calculate what the actual width/height units come out as on a full-screen page and I'm not sure exactly how the units are calculated?
It seems MAUI may be sparse on documentation related to this, are the Xamarin docs still relevant (as this older answer proposes)? It's hard to know how much has changed and I might be mathing wrong somewhere, but if I take the documentation that links to along with my not-quite-device-accurate "Pixel 5" emulator with a resolution of 1080x2340 and a DPI of 440 the numbers don't work out quite right. I tinkered given the following measurements:
DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height: 2340
DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width: 1080
DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density: 2.75

2.75 * 160 = 440dpi, so the density seems to match the docs
2340 / 440 = 5.31818..." tall
1080 / 440 = 2.4545..." wide 
5.31818..." * 160dps = 850.9090...dps, should be the full height of the display
2.4545..." * 160dps = 392.7272...dps, should be the full width of the display

but my observations didn't match my expectations, so I added an override void OnSizeAllocated into a launch page that is almost full height (expecting something just under the above 850 leaving some room for the notification/action bars) and wrote out the actual width/height which showed:
OnSizeAllocated, width: 320, height: 654.1818181818181

So based on these measurements, it seems like the screen is only 2 inches wide and the height is perceived as 4 inches tall. I have no idea how to predict/calculate these seemingly arbitrary differences from the (Xamarin) docs. Has MAUI changed the behavior? Is there a factor I'm not taking into consideration?
Let's say I wanted to specify something should have a max-width of 2.5 inches or change the height of something if the screen is taller than 5 inches, how would I express that (preferably in C#, as this app is not using XAML)? If it makes a difference, I only need this to work for iOS and Android. Alternatively, if there's no guidance for what I'm looking for, is there a nice easy cross-platform way to ask what the device's physical screen dimensions are that I might use to better boil down these ratios?

After a bit of digging I found the cause of the inconsistency was actually in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I had to view the raw xml rather than the editor and found this suspicious looking line which ended up being the reason the width was fixed:
<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" />



2340 / 440 = 5.31818..." tall 1080 / 440 = 2.4545..." wide

This is the way to use the DPI to calulate the height and width.Usually, mobile phone manufacturers calculate pixel density with PPI.
If you need to convert pixel dimensions to PPI, you can use formula. It provides both automatic conversion and a manual formula. The formula is:
PPI = Diagonal In Pixels / Diagonal In Inches

To calculate the diagonal in pixels, use:
Diagonal In Pixels = √(width² + height²)


The issue I'm having has more to do with translating to MAUI display units (which are not measured in PPI). Nothing about the PPI/Density seems to add up to having a full-screen width of 320 units; I don't know how 1080 pixels wide is translated into 320 units wide. The 1080 is accurate, and the 440 dpi is accurate and I know the device is ~2.5" wide. What I don't know is how any of those numbers relates to 320 units wide.

I did the calculations in your post and can confirm a ppi of ~440. Diagonal inches: 5.860034129593445, Diagonal pixels: 2577.207791389744, PPI = 439.7939899999429. 440 / 2.75 (Density) = 160 units per inch. Width of 320 = 2 inches, where did the other half an inch go?

Maui uses the MainDisplayInfo.Density to calculate the maximum pixels:
DisplayMaxHeight = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

DisplayMaxWidth = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

see also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.displayinfo.density

The issue we ran into was that it lied about the width itself, though it turned out there was a setting in the android manifest (no idea why, I wasn't the one who added it) which forced any screen wider than 320 dip to be reported as 320 dip wide.
